# Is it possible to get videos from facebook fan page using oauth?

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth, facebook-page

I am building an application which already retrieves comments and photos from the fan page, using the oauth ID.

When I change the request to : https://graph.facebook.com/wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww/videos/uploaded?access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy

It returns me the following error: 
"{
   "error": {
      "message": "A user access token is required to request this resource.",
      "type": "OAuthException"
   }
}"

I can't find the reason why facebook doesn't let me get the videos, maybe copyrights?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: You only can authenticate using oauth, you probably meant OpenGraph...

Comment: My main question is, is it possible to get facebook fan page videos, without the user login? I am trying to do that using an appId... And I was able to retrieve the comments and the photos, but when I try the videos it returns me that error!

Comment: which method are you using to get access token? can you put up that code here?

Comment: I just followed the rules to get the acesstoken for apps, and I putt the link together. The acess token is valid because I can retrieve comments and photos. but it doesnt work with videos...

Comment: well ok, i need to know what permissions you have asked for, if any. i think i have a solution, but not sure. permissions from the user when user authorizes your app

Comment: I am not using user login. I am usid "app login" just to get the information on a certain facebook page. Do I have to ask for any permissions?

Comment: sorry, i'm not sure how app login works. But have you tried the graph api explorer? it will help you in deciding if you need any permissions to view the videos. you can use it to explore fields/connections for pages too, and not just users. maybe you will need an access token for the page admin, as that's the error you are getting(user access token). Again i'm not sure if all that will help.

Comment: yes check this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7874301/facebook-api-bug

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong URL to retrieve videos it should be **/page-id/videos** not **/page-id/videos/uploaded**

Comment: So your saying that I should use this link: https://graph.facebook.com/page-id/videos?access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy correct? It returns me the same error: {
   "error": {
      "message": "A user access token is required to request this resource.",
      "type": "OAuthException"
   }
}

Comment: As stated in documentation: "any valid access_token or user access_token" is required

Comment: yes, i know... but i don't understand what is the reason for the error returned when i send that request, taking in consideration that i can retrieve the photos and the comments using that same acess_token...