# Facebook api BUG?

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am building an iphone app that reads the videos uploaded , photos uploaded and posts from facebook. The photos and the videos are not from the feed, they are from the albums. So I got an access token for my app (not a user access token) and got it working for the photos and posts. But when I try to get the videos it returns me the following error:

```
{
   "error": {
     "message": "A user access token is required to request this resource.",
   "type": "OAuthException"
  }
}
```

The documentation for pages (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/) claims that all of these connections can be accessed by any app or user access token, but the error message received implies that a user token is required. Is this a bug?

Comment: Please post the actual API call you're making.

Comment: https://graph.facebook.com/yyyyyyyyyy/videos?access_token=xxxxxxxxxxx-wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww

Comment: and https://graph.facebook.com/yyyyyyyyyy/posts?access_token=xxxxxxxxxxx-wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww

Comment: and https://graph.facebook.com/yyyyyyyyyy/notes?access_token=xxxxxxxxxxx-wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww

Comment: A user access_token and an 'app' access token are not separate things.  An 'app' access token, is a user access token with the `manage_pages` permission in the scope.  In the error that you're stating, it sounds like you aren't passing an access_token, otherwise it would implicitly say that the access_token is invalid.

Comment: Coulton, that's not correct. App access tokens are a distinct concept from user access tokens. A user access token involves a user authorizing an app and can be used by the app to perform actions and fetch data in the context of the user. An app access token is exchanged for the app secret, and is typically used to perform actions on behalf of the app itself (NOT a page).

Comment: exactly @Yuliy . But still I haven't found the answer for my problem :(

Comment: If you want to query the user's video you should call https://graph.facebook.com/me/videos?access_token=USER_ACCESS_TOKEN with the 'user_videos' permissions.

Comment: you are not correct. check this link : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/   as you can see in the connections table, the field permissions for videos: any valid access_token or user access_token

Comment: I dont want the user's video. I want the page's videos ( in an album per example )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the bug has been confirmed and assigned

http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/234838783244280

Answer (score 0):

try something like this.. just convert the string to a URL..

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/videos/uploaded?date_format=U&access_token=%@",[authenticationKey_ stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need permissions for user's videos and pictures.